# Regular expression for arabic with spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I have to validate arabic letters using regular expression.

For the same I use the below one

```
^[\u0600-\u06ff]+$
```

its works for Arabic characters without spaces. To accept with spaces I modified the regular expression as below

```
 ^[\u0600-\u06ff]?(\w)+$
 ^[\u0600-\u06ff]?[\w]+$
 ^[\u0600-\u06ff?\w]+$
```

but all the method failed and not passing for Arabic characters without spaces also.

Please help me to include spaces also with the same.

Answer (score 2):

Just add space to the character class to match the spaces

```
^[\u0600-\u06ff ]+$
```

Comment: :) easy one..Thanks..no need to go with \w and all

Answer (score 1):

Just include `\s` inside the character class.

```
^[\u0600-\u06ff\s]+$
```